# How use autoresizing programmatically IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autoresize

I have made a code without storyboard for Iphone 5 (8.1) with some subviews. It's working for Iphone 5 device but it doesn't for the others… I have tried to insert autoresizing function but I don't know why it still doesn't work.

Here my code:

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "RevealViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()
@property UIView *blurMask;
@property UIImageView *blurredBgImage;
@end

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize blurMask, blurredBgImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self Blur:blurredBgImage];
}

- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[self view] setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    // content view
    [self.view addSubview:[self createContentView]];

    // slide view
    [self.view addSubview:[self createScrollView]];

    blurMask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    blurMask.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    blurredBgImage.layer.mask = blurMask.layer;

}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    blurMask.frame = CGRectMake(blurMask.frame.origin.x,
                            self.view.frame.size.height - 0 - scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                            blurMask.frame.size.width,
                            blurMask.frame.size.height + scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}

- (UIView *)createContentView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [contentView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [contentView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    UIImageView *contentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.frame];
    contentImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-ground.png"];
    [contentView addSubview:contentImage];
    return contentView;
}

- (UIView *)createScrollView{
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [containerView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [containerView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    blurredBgImage = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -57, self.view.frame.size.width, 568)];
    [blurredBgImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [containerView addSubview:blurredBgImage];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [containerView addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,  self.view.frame.size.height*2 - 110);
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    UIView *slideContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 455, self.view.frame.size.width, 508)];

    slideContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:slideContentView];

    UILabel *slideUpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    slideUpLabel.text = @"Informations";
    [slideUpLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18]];
    [slideUpLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [slideUpLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    slideUpLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
    [slideContentView addSubview:slideUpLabel];

    UIImageView *slideUpImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 12, 4, 24, 22.5)];
    slideUpImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up-arrow.png"];
    [slideContentView addSubview:slideUpImage];

    UITextView *detailsText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 275, 350)];
    detailsText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailsText.text = @"Details text… with information ";
    [detailsText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16]];
    [detailsText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    detailsText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.6];

    [slideContentView addSubview:detailsText];

    UIImageView *Facebook = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 260, 42, 42)];
    Facebook.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];

    [slideContentView addSubview:Facebook];

    UIImageView *Twitter = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(168, 260, 42, 42)];
    Twitter.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"];

    [slideContentView addSubview:Twitter];

    UITextView *rsText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 275, 350)];
    rsText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    rsText.text = @"Text Facebook text Twitter. mail ";
    [rsText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16]];
    [rsText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    rsText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.6];

    [slideContentView addSubview:rsText];

    UITextView *endText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 450, 270, 350)];
    endText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    endText.text = @"Thank you ";
    [endText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12]];
    [endText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    endText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.6];

    [slideContentView addSubview:endText];

    return containerView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)Blur:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *blurView=nil;
    if ([UIBlurEffect class]) {
        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect= [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
        blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        blurView.frame = view.frame;
    }else {
        blurView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];

    }
    [blurView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view addSubview:blurView];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[blurView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[blurView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];

}

@end
```

Any idea? Feedback?
Thank you.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I usually create views like that in the storyboard and add constraints with auto layout on. If I need to create something universal in code I do a bit of math and put things where they need to go. It's all trial and error. I really haven't grasped the programmatic constraints/autoresize

Answer (score 1):

The following falls more under feedback:

1. This looks like you code was copy/pasted, but your `@property` calls don't specify the atomicity or how ARC should treat them, so perhaps this was somewhat paraphrased.
2. If you're programmatically going to create a view controller, it doesn't call `initWithNib:`
3. To assign target/action to a button, you'll be using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`
4. `@synthesize` isn't needed unless you're going to write a custom setter
5. methods in Objc always begin with a lowercase letter ( `[MenuViewController  Blur]` )
6. From the `loadView` documentation:

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.
>
> If you're explicitly setting the view controllers `view` property to have a frame of `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`, you don't need to set its autoresizing behavior -- it's already going to match the size of the screen. This goes for all of your views that you're doing this for.
>
> Not sure the reason behind subtracting 0 here: `self.view.frame.size.height - 0 - scrollView.contentOffset.y`
>
> There's quite a bit going on in your `createScrollView` method... it's hard to follow without having comments in your code or some sort of image that shows where each of those subviews are. The view heirarchy being set up seems overly complicated and might be best done in a custom subclassed `UIView` or `UIScrollView`. I would think of it this way: could you easily tell what this view would look like if you didn't look at this code for a month?
>
> This is likely working on only the 5 as you're setting `UIKit` elements to specific locations in the frame, rather than using autolayout or autoresizing masks (use autolayout though, it's the future and apple has a tendency to stop supporting older technologies)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what parts of your code may be intentional without more context. However, it looks like you're adding an autoresizing mask to the contentView and scrollView but not any of the subviews of those two. For example, in your createContentView method if you want the UIImageView to resize when the contentView resizes you would need to add autoresizing constraints to the UIImageView as well. i.e. imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

Same with all of the subviews of your slideContentView.